# Traversing though a list of objects in java

Tags: java, arrays, list, spring-boot, loops

First of all i am very new to Java so if my question isn't complete with details, please excuse me. I did go through a few threads on SO, even though there were some close ones, i didn't understand them or couldn't modify them as per my need. So here is the question, below is list of objects that i am getting from a repo.

`[
  {
    "esId": 3,
    "exam": {
      "examId": 1,
      "name": "Final Exam",
      "startDate": "2019-04-15",
      "endDate": "2019-04-24",
      "resultReleaseDate": "2019-04-30 07:00:00"
    }
  },
  {
    "esId": 44,
    "exam": {
      "examId": 15,
      "name": "Mid Term II",
      "startDate": "2019-09-20",
      "endDate": "2019-09-25",
      "resultReleaseDate": "2019-09-25 18:32:02"
    },
    "essList": [
      {
        "esdId": 74,
        "subject": {
          "subjectId": 1,
          "name": "Math"
        },
        "exDate": "2019-09-20",
        "startTime": "19:03",
        "maxMarks": 10,
        "endTime": "19:03"
      },
      {
        "esdId": 77,
        "subject": {
          "subjectId": 2,
          "name": "Science"
        },
        "exDate": "2019-09-21",
        "startTime": "19:03",
        "maxMarks": 10,
        "endTime": "19:03"
      },
      {
        "esdId": 79,
        "subject": {
          "subjectId": 3,
          "name": "English"
        },
        "exDate": "2019-09-20",
        "startTime": "19:04",
        "maxMarks": 10,
        "endTime": "19:04"
      }
    ]
  }
]`

From the above list i want to return the first object whose `endDate` is greater than `now` or `today`

I tried doing the following way

```
ArrayList<ExamStandard> examList = new ArrayList<ExamStandard>();
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        String date = today.toString();
        for(int i = 0; i < examList.size(); i++)
        {
            if(examList.get(i).equals(exam) == date){

            }
        }
```

This started throwing error of conversion types. Not sure how to do this, if anybody can help me and explain me how to do and whats happening, would be really helpful.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks
Vikram

Comment: equals return boolean and you are trying to compare it to a string. Makes no sense

Comment: What do you expect the line `if(examList.get(i).equals(exam) == date)` to do? The `equals` returns a `boolean` which you then compare to a `String`. That makes no sense at all.

Comment: You should create a `Comparator` in your `ExamStandard class` that compares two date and use `compareTo` to find what you need

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume you reached to your `exDate` and it is in string format.

First of all, do the following

```
String sDate1="31/12/1998";  
    Date date1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(sDate1);  
    System.out.println(sDate1+"\t"+date1);
```

`date1` is now in the format Date

Later, you can use predefined date methods as mentioned below

```
          if(date1.after(date2)){
                System.out.println("Date1 is after Date2");
            }
            // before() will return true if and only if date1 is before date2
            if(date1.before(date2)){
                System.out.println("Date1 is before Date2");
            }

            //equals() returns true if both the dates are equal
            if(date1.equals(date2)){
                System.out.println("Date1 is equal Date2");
            }
```

Where date2 is maybe your current date or any date you want to give.

To return what you need do this

```
ExamList exam = new ExamList();
SimpleDateFormat sd=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");  
int i = 0;
foreach(ExamList ex : examList){
  if(sd.parse(ex.getExDate()).after(date)){
    exam = ex;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Just try.

Let me know if some tweaks needed, I can get in my computer instead of the phone.

Note: You may need to add necessary null checks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kunal, but may be i wasn't clear enough in my post. So here's the thing. I have got the response as the above list, i want to know how do i traverse through that list and search the list for the date which matches the 'endDate' of the list of objects and it should return that object.

Comment: Yes this is how you will go.
i)Loop over to the list of data you have
ii)Do date comparison
iii)Whereever condition is true, you return that part of list back i.e. single object from that list.